# When querying over many lquery, should I query an array of lqueries or join them using '|'?

Tags: postgresql, performance, ltree

When using the `ltree` PostgreSQL extension, there are these two operators (among others) at our disposal to compare `ltree` columns to `lquery`s.

```sql
ltree ~ lquery
ltree ? lquery[]
```

It seems that you should use `~` for single queries and `?` for multiple queries. However, you can also join queries with the use of the `|` logical OR operator.

So, these two are equivalent when it comes to the queried results:

```sql
ltree ~ lquery1 || "|" || lquery2
ltree ? {lquery1, lquery2}
```

Which of these forms should I prefer?